# Emacs Pymacs Ropemacs return to previous file after goto definition

Tags: python, emacs, ide, pymacs, ropemacs

I use Emacs + pymacs + ropemacs.I can use C-c g to go to the definition of objects,as mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2855895/4018217 ,but after I go the definition ,how do I return to the file or the position from where I issued the command.

I have been using bookmark in emacs to navigate till now.

Comment: Hey, would you mind check and edit this installation procedure ? thank you very much ! http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Python#Refactoring

Comment: I did update the installation procedure,itll be great if you could test it yourself.I still haven't tried the evil mode,I was hoping there was a ropemacs keyboard binding to go back to previous buffer.

Comment: I saw that, thank you very much ! The procedure worked for me. I can at last discover rope, and its rename feature is already handy ! (it is pretty nice to be able to see a preview for every command). I didn't manage to test the `el-get` recipe though.

Answer (score 0):

With [evil-mode](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil), you can use evil-jumper: http://melpa.org/#/evil-jumper . It is a replacement of the jump list with the added feature that it can jump accross files and buffers.

The base use of `C-o` and `C-i` in evil are to go to the previous/next position of the cursor in the current buffer. With evil-jumper, we are not limited to the current buffer.

Comment: I haven't used the evil mode till now,ill let you know if it works,I'll also get to the installation procedure as well.